# removing whitespace and transform lowercase in url? how?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, removing-whitespace

i am trying to add a rewrite rule to the htaccess which overwrites the url structure
from :

```
example.com?user=laura&baked=cakes
```

to:

```
example.com/user/laura/baked/cakes
```

while i managed to do that fine, i found that it does not display the spaces properly in  the url: ie. `baked/Lovely Chocolate Cake/` is shown as 
`baked/Lovely%20Chocolate%20Cake/`. 
the thing im trying to achieve is to overwrite the whitespace (%20) and make it a - or + and turning it all to lowercase.
i managed to get to this code following reading on SO so far:

```
RewriteRule ^/user/([a-z]+)/baked/([a-z\ .*A-Zx0-9-_]+)$ cakesmade.php?id=$1&baked=$2
```

your input is welcome. the htaccess language seems a bit difficult to interpret.

Comment: Changing the case to lowercase requires Apache config change. Do you have access to that?

Comment: if its the htaccess file then yes.

Comment: No that is apache server config, you need to have admin access to make that change.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that. in the `.htaccess` (before actual `RewriteRule`):

```
RewriteRule ^/user/.*[A-Z\ ] /linkChange.php?l=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

and in `linkChange.php` :

```
<?
    $link = $_GET['l'];
    $newlink = strtr($link," ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ","-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    header("Location: http://www.example.com". $newlink,TRUE,301); exit;
?>
```

Comment: thanks croises. that is helpful. with my code is the structure correct for the second parenthesis?  `RewriteRule ^/user/([a-z]+)/baked/([a-z\ .*A-Zx0-9-_]+)$ cakesmade.php?id=$1&baked=$2`
and with the code you posted, if all url is in lower case i still wish to apply the + or a - instead of a whitespace, does the code  need to remain the same?

Comment: You can use `[a-z.*0-9_-]` for the second test in your `RewriteRule`.

Comment: in the url bar: it shows the url twice, but even when i correct it the second part of the url (lowercase and with - instead of spaces) and go there, it does not display correctly. the arrays are capitalized such as `Lovely Chocolate Cake`. do the arrays need to be in lower case as well? or is there a problem with my code?

Comment: Use that: `RewriteRule ^/user/([a-z]+)/baked/([a-z.*0-9_-]+)$ cakesmade.php?id=$1&baked=$2`

Comment: **im sorry i wasnt very clear with my wording.what i meant was this:**
`example.com/user/laura/baked/cakes` > it displays the intended page
`example.com/user/laura/baked/Lovely%20Chocolate%20cake` > it displays the intended page
`example.com/user/laura/baked/lovely-chocolate-cakeexample.com/user/laura/baked/lovely-chocolate-cake` > this is what happens after linkchange, it does not show the intended page
 
and when i go to this page `example.com/user/laura/baked/lovely-chocolate-cake` > it does not display the record acts as if its not in the array. 
**any ideas?**

Comment: I change the link as you request. But now it is clear that in your php program, you must also take steps to make it possible to find the correct content with this new link.

Comment: yes that seems to be the tricky part. thank you for the pointer so far.